# Is it valid to increment a state object value inside setState(); without cloning the object?

Tags: reactjs, object, state, clone, dplyr

Incrementing some `ingredients` value inside `setState(return {})` without cloning `ingredients`. Is it OK?

```
state = {
   // The object I need to increment its value.
   ingredients: {
      sugar: 0,
      salt: 0,
      pepper: 0
   },
   count: 0
}

addSugarHandler = () => {
   this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return {
         // Incrementing some `ingredients` value
         // inside `setState()` without cloning it.
         // Is it OK?
         ingredients: prevState.ingredients.sugar + 1,
         // I am sure the following is valid
         count: prevState.count + 1
      };
   });
}
```

Comment: This will not work as you intend it i think. This will just overwrite your ingredients with not an object, but with the number in suger +1 instead. So, sure, you can do that, but your ingredient object is lost in the process.

Comment: Initially `ingredients` was an object. After the first update it becomes a number. After that it always will be `NaN`. So the answer is no, unless you really need such a weird behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @YuryTarabanko , I did not notice that very incorrect incrementing :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko BTW :) is that last line valid? `count: prevState.count + 1`

Comment: @SalehRezq LGTM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like that.But there is some correction needed.
Should be like this.

```
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return {
       ingredients: {
         ...ingredients,
         sugar: prevState.ingredients.sugar + 1
       },
       count: prevState.count + 1
     };
   });
```

Comment: count was not part of state.ingredients, you should move it down one line